# Creating custom color styles for an XSSFWorkbook in Apache POI 4.0

Tags: java, apache-poi

To apply a custom color for an XSSFWorkbook in Apache POI 3.7 and below the following was possible:

```
java.awt.Color c = new java.awt.Color (1,2,3)
XSSFCellStyle xcs = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont headerFont = xssfWorkbook.createFont();
headerFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(c));
xcs.setFont(headerFont);
cell.setCellStyle(xcs);
```

In version 4.0 XSSFColor(java.awt.Color) got removed. It is still possible to 
achieve the same, just with additional 'hackery':

```
XSSFColor xc = new XSSFColor();
xc.setARGBHex(String.format("%02x%02x%02x",c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue())); 
headerFont.setColor(xc);
```

But what is the 'proper' way to do this? Most of the XSSFColor methods involve an IndexedColorMap but I could not find any example for how this could be used for setting custom colors in an XSSFWorkbook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
byte[] rgb = {120, 100, (byte) 200};
headerFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(rgb, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context regarding the DefaultIndexedColorMap? What is this actually good for? Should this be created only once per workbook?

Comment: yeah, you could create one instance of DefaultIndexedColorMap. It implements IndexedColorMap -an interface for color index to RGB mappings. DefaultIndexedColorMap uses the legacy colors defined in HSSF for index lookups. HSSFColor contains static inner class members for representing colors. Each color has an index (for the standard palette in Excel (tm) ), native (RGB) triplet and string triplet. In Apache POI 3.7 you applied a custom color using `public XSSFColor(CTColor color) {
        this(color, new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
    }` method with default color indexes

Comment: What about values in array? 0 - r, 1 - g, 2 - b? 
Should we reuse colorMap for whole workbook? How to reuse that color? 
Answer has poor quality as POI documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();      
    byte[] rgb = {20, (byte) 230, 25};
    XSSFColor xc = new XSSFColor(rgb, null);
    font.setColor(xc);
```

Above should be the best way for POI4.*.