# How to set a cell's color to an RGB value in apache poi 4.0

Tags: apache-poi

The example here does not compile. setFillForegroundColor now seems to want an index, I can trick it to show specific colors, but trying any method at specifying an rgb value just creates a black cell.

Below is apache's own example which seems to be out of date with 4.0. 
https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell( 0);
cell.setCellValue("custom XSSF colors");

XSSFCellStyle style1 = wb.createCellStyle();
style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128)));
style1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Comment: try `style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357448/creating-custom-color-styles-for-an-xssfworkbook-in-apache-poi-4-0/52360309#52360309

Comment: @PJ Fanning: What is that `new DefaultIndexedColorMap()` for? It is useless until now. So why not simply `style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), null));`? If `DefaultIndexedColorMap` becomes sense in further releases of `apache poi` code must be changed anyway because of other changes. This was always the case after release changes until now.

Comment: Thank you @PJFanning that did the trick perfectly. You are correct that this is an apparent duplicate, for some reason when I ran into that solution previously I could not get it to work, but I must have made a mistake because your specific example as well as theirs is working for me with the defaultindexedcolormap now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating custom color styles for an XSSFWorkbook in Apache POI 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357448/creating-custom-color-styles-for-an-xssfworkbook-in-apache-poi-4-0)